# OpenCL, substituting branches with arithmetic operations

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpu

The following question is more related to design, rather than actual coding. I don't know if there's a technical term for such problem, so I'll proceed with an example.

I have some openCL code not optimized at all, and in the Kernel there's essentially a switch statement similar to the following

```
switch(const) {
   case const_a : do_something_a(...); break;
   case const_b : do_something_b(....); break;
   ... //etc
}
```

I cannot write the actual statement since is quite long. As a simple example consider the following switch statement:

```
int a;
switch(input):
  case 13 : {a = 3; break;}
  case 1 : {a = 7; break;}
  case 23 : {a = 1; break;}
  default : {...}
```

The question is... would it be better to change such switch with an expression like

`a = (input == 13)*3 + (input == 1)*7 + (input == 23)`

?

If it's not, is it possible to make it more efficient anyway?

You can assume `input` only takes values in the set of cases of the switch statement.

Comment: Does this mean there's no way you could suggest to write that bit more efficiently?

Comment: Done, question edited.

Comment: This is like shooting in the dark. This is what I would do, look at the code generated if possible. If you can't see what compiler is doing then you can benchmark and see if there is any benefit. If OpenCL driver is optimized it might figure out that these are constants and generated multiple binaries (called function specialization), you could do that same, create multiple kernels making using MACROS and build programs for each constant `-DMYCONST=13` and conditionals should get optimized by any decent compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You've discovered an interesting question that GPU compilers wrestle with.  The general advice is *try not to branch*.  Tricks to make that possible are splitting kernels up (as suggested above) and preprocessor (program-time definitions).  Research in GPU algorithm development basically works from this axiom.

Branching all over the place won't get great efficiency because of the inherent divergence (channel = work item within the SIMD thread/warp).  Remember that all these channels must execute together.  So in a switch where all are taking different paths everyone else goes along for the ride silently waiting for their "case" to execute.  Now, if `input` is always always the same value, it can still be a win.

Another popular option is a table indirection.

```
kernel void foo(const int *t, ...)
  ...
  a = tbl[input];
```

This case has a few problems too depending on hardware, inputs, and problem size.

Without more specific context, I can conjure up a case where any of these can run well or poorly.

- Switching (or big if-then-else chains).

  - PROS: If all work items generally take the same path (`input` is mostly the same value), it's going to be efficient.  You could also write an if-then-else chain putting the most common cases first.  (On GPUs a switch is not necessarily as easy as an indirect jump since there are multiple work items and they may take different paths.)
  - CONS: Might generate lots of program code and could blow out the instruction cache.  Branching all over the place can get a little costly depending on how many cases need to be evaluated.  It might just be better to grind through the compute with the predicated code.
- Predicated Code (Your `(input == 13)*3 ...` code).

  - PROS: This will probably generate smaller programs and stress the I$ less.  (Lookup the [OpenCL select](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/select.html) function to see a more general approach for your case.)
  - CONS: We've basically punted and decided to evaluate every "case in the switch".  If `input` is usually the same value, we're wasting time here.
- Lookup-table based approaches (my example).

  - PROS: If the switch you are evaluating has a massive number of cases (branches), but can be indexed by integer you might be ahead to just use a lookup table.  On some hardware this means a read from global memory (far far away).  Other architectures have a dedicated constant cache, but I understand that a vector lookup will serialize (K cycles for each channel).  So it might be only marginally better than the global memory table.  However, the code table-lookup generated will be short (I$ friendly) and as the number of branches (case statements) grow this will win in the limit.  This approach also deals well with uniform/scattered distributions of `input`'s value.
  - CONS: The read from global memory (or serialized access from the constant cache) has a big latency even compared to branching.  In some cases, to eliminate the extra memory traffic I've seen compilers convert lookup tables into if-then-else/switch chains.  It's rare that we have 100 element case statements.

I am now inspired to go study this cutoff. :-)

Comment: I was thinking about the LUT approach, the thing is I don't know how to map those constants to indices.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the problem have a specific name? So maybe I can look up some examples.

Comment: *Divergence* is generally the term used in SIMD/SIMT hardware for when workitems (SIMD channels) take different paths. There is no easy way to do it well and the examples above are all attempting to reduce the impact.